# When I unplug my headphones, my speakers (and headphones) stop working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, headphones

Happens intermittently:
When I unplug my Sony headphones, I am unable to get my 17" MBP (2.8ghz intel core 2 duo, running Lion), to make any sound. I've tried a handful of different hardware, and nothing will make a peep.

Restarting "fixes" it.

Comment: Have you tried simply reinserting the headphones and pulling them back out again? Sometimes pulling headphones out too quickly can leave the OS confused.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug Lion has.

[This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3220787?start=0&tstart=0) should provide you with more info of users suffering the same bug.

[This app](http://kyen99.tumblr.com/post/8573258536/mac-os-x-lion-audio-fix) claims to fix it (I found it on that same thread).

I haven't had the bug for a while, but I did have it quite a bit before. I really hope Apple fixes it, by 10.7.2 perhaps.

Hope it helps!

**Edit**: Probably the most relevant information in the thread is that it seems to be a bug on Core Audio. `$ sudo killall coreaudiod` quits the process and the system automatically restarts it, effectively providing a quick fix to the bug. The rest are people posting about their personal experiences and thanking the developer of the app that automatically applies this fix.

Comment: Please add the relevant content to your answer; if those links die, your answer becomes useless.

It's also worth noting it happens to me on 10.10 with a Late 2013 MBPr 15-inch.